# Using join to concatenate array values

Tags: arrays, perl

I have array values that is getting returned from SQL object.

```
my @keys = $db_obj->SelectAllArrayRef($sql);
print Dumper @keys;
```

gives

```
$VAR1 = [ [ '8853' ], [ '15141' ] ];
```

I need to create string from this array: `8853, 15141`.

```
my $inVal = join(',', map { $_->[0] }, @$keys);

my $inVal;
foreach my $result (@$keys){
    $inVal .= $result->[0];
}

my $inVal = join(',', @$keys);
```

Value i get is `ARRAY(0x5265498),ARRAY(0x52654e0)`. I think its reference to the array.  Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: How is `$keys` related to your `$VAR1` example ?

Comment: my @keys = $db_obj->SelectAllArrayRef($sql);
print Dumper @keys;      Result from Dumper is $VAR1 = [ [ '8853' ], [ '15141' ] ];

Comment: You would capture an array reference as `my ($aref) = $db_obj->....`  In perl, `$keys` and `@keys` are different variables (!).  `$keys` is a scalar variable holding a value or a reference to something else.  `@keys` is an array.  See `perldoc perlref` for the gory details.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the output you claim it does because `@keys` isn't the same as `@$keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass arrays to `Dumper`; it leads to confusing output. `$VAR1` is not a dump of `@keys`, it's a dump of `$keys[0]`. Instead, you should have done

```
print(Dumper(\@keys));
```

This would have given

```
$VAR1 = [ [ [ '8853' ], [ '15141' ] ] ];
```

The code you want is

```
join ',', map { $_->[0] }, @{ $keys[0] };
```

---

That said, it appears that `->SelectAllArrayRef` returns a reference to the result, and so it should be called as follows:

```
my $keys = $db_obj->SelectAllArrayRef($sql);
```

For this,

```
print(Dumper($keys));
```

outputs

```
$VAR1 = [ [ '8853' ], [ '15141' ] ];
```

And you may use either of the methods you used in your question.

```
join ',', map { $_->[0] }, @$keys;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first version should work for you:

```
my $arr = [ [ '8853' ], [ '15141' ] ];
my $values = join(',', map { $_->[0] } @$arr);
print $values . "\n";

8853,15141
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working ...:(  in the context... seems to work as script thought.

Comment: @Kris1511  Then show us that context please.  Edit the question and show the code that sets this up.  Otherwise, your first two attempts are good (the last one would give what you show, two reference-stringifications)